How to have different options in different server Discord.py
I've seen some robot that have command settings, but I can't find how to do it...
Like some economy bots have a /item info, and they have different options for "item" argument because every server has its own items.
Or some bot support multiple languages, which you can change it in /setting or some commands like that, and the caption for commands will change to a different language.
Is it possible to make this with a database?
I tried to find the solution on internet but there's no any tutorial, and I don't know what keyword to search in the discord.py document.
